# C# MVC Application Deployment Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, deployment

I have made an application in MVC4.0 and deployed on Server.

Application is running fine in VS2013 i.e. Development enviroment. But when I have deployed it on server, I am getting:

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden.
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
Most likely causes:
A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

I am a bit new for web development I am also attaching my web.config(I have two web.config files one in main folder and other in Views folder.), if there is any issue in that. I have seen while gooling that we need to add some tag in web.config for routes. But I dont find that tag.

Comment: Is MVC 4 installed on the server?

Answer (score -2):

Having two Web.Config's is correct and if the website works locally then you shouldn't need to add any routes. Generally if the server is returning that error then you have pointed the webserver at the wrong directory. I assume you are using IIS? You need to go into the site configuration and check that the folder you set IIS to point at in basic settings is the folder that directly contains the main Web.Config. If that doesn't work then make sure that IIS can access the files. Usually if IIS can't access the files you need to add 'IIS_IUSRS' to the permissions of the folder the website is contained in

Comment: Posting from a cell phone works better if you have automatic sentence capitalization turned on.  Most modern cell phones have this capability; if yours doesn't, consider using a real computer to post your answers.

Comment: i wrote this on my laptop. if i had have written it on my iphone then yes it would have been autocapitalised. i didn't think i was doing an english test though

Comment: This is a professional website, not an Internet Forum.  We expect a nominal amount of effort from our users to post actual English sentences.  We don't believe that expectation is unduly onerous or oppressive.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Tom, I have upload the site on public server. They told me that they have MVC4 installed and have all rights given to site and they are saying that there is some issue in web.config file.

Comment: Are there any stack traces or log errors other than the one you put in the question? What company is it hosted with? It could be that a DLL is missing on the hosted environment. If you can find out which DLL is missing then you can right click the reference to the DLL in visual studio and set copy local to true. Then make sure you build and upload all DLLs in the bin folder